# Raspberry Pi 3 Overclocking and Warranty

Tags: overclocking

I found the following at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md:

> The specific circumstances where the overclock bit is set are if force_turbo is set to 1 and any of the over_voltage_* options are set to a value > 0

Does that mean that I can overclock as much as I want if I don't force the Pi3 to run at the set frequency constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked just after the paragraph you quoted, it links to [this blog post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-turbo-mode-up-to-50-more-performance-for-free/). In that page, it's stated that:

> We’ve been doing a lot of work to understand the impact of voltage and temperature on lifetime, and are now able to offer a “turbo mode”, which dynamically enables overclock and overvolt under the control of a cpufreq driver, without affecting your warranty.

So long as you don't set `force_turbo`, which forces turbo mode to run even when not necessary, the warranty void bit will likely not be set. This is confirmed by [one of the engineers at the Foundation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=176865#p176865), who states:

> Note, that overclocking through raspi-config doesn't set your "warranty" bit. What sets the warranty bit now, is:
>
> ```
> (force_turbo || current_limit_override || temp_limit>85) && over_voltage>0
> ```
>
> So, if you are manually overclocking and want to know what is "allowed", then stick to those config.txt options.
>   If you've already blown your warranty bit, or don't care, then feel free to change anything.

**In practice, this means you're limited to a 1.35 V core voltage**, because without `force_turbo` or `current_limit_override`, you can only set `over_voltage` to a [maximum of 6](https://elinux.org/RPiconfig).

Answer (score 0):

The warranty void flag shouldn't be triggered, as long as you don't force the Pi to operate above 85C through overclocking and force_turbo being off. If you are worried about your warrenty being void, you can check by running `cat /proc/cpuinfo`. Look for the 'Revision' line. If it is a 4 digit alphanumeric number, the your warrenty isn't void. If the revision starts with 1000, then it is void.